# How can I return a RichText field via an API and render links correctly?

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-api

In my item I have a RichText field that I am returning the value via an api (API controller called from jQuery).

In the response, I am able to render the value.

But issue is that my RichText field value contains an item link like this: `<a href="~/link.aspx?_id=67HTg5464321&amp;_z=z">here</a>`

Do we have any option to render my RichText field using HTML.RAW in jQuery or any other option to do the same arrangement in controller before returning to jQuery response.

As I want my link item to converted before rendering to the friendly url (ex: https://domain/abc/dec).

Comment: What API are you using? To get the link returned correctly, you are going to need to run the field through the FieldRenderer pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get the value of a rich text field like

```
item["richtext"]
```

you will receive raw value of the field, including internally formatted links like `<a href="~/link.aspx?_id=67HTg5464321&amp;_z=z">here</a>`

You need to add the following code to render value of the field:

```
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item;
string fieldName;

var fieldRenderer = new Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.FieldRenderer();
fieldRenderer.Item = item;
fieldRenderer.FieldName = fieldName;
fieldRenderer.DisableWebEditing = true;
RenderFieldResult renderFieldResult = fieldRenderer.RenderField();
string richTextFieldValue = renderFieldResult.ToString();
```